# Using enumerate to select random member of list

Tags: python, enumerate

Lets say mylist is list of 70 elements, I would like to random select 0,12,5 elements from mylist. I get syntax error at "rand:"

```
rand = [0, 12, 5]
LL=[]
for x in enumerate(mylist) if i in rand:
        LL.append(x)
```

Comment: What is `i`?  It's not defined.

Comment: How is this random selection? It's just selecting the elements from `[0, 12, 5]` (and @Sven is right, `i` is not defined).

Comment: Merlin: There *is* no enumerate's `i` in your code. Perhaps (like @mgilson assumes) you mean `for i, x in enumerate(mylist)`?

Comment: I think I have used i with enumerate without defining it.

Comment: rand will be set later, hard coded it here as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: @Merlin, I guarantee that you have not.

Comment: @Merlin -- If the variable `i` was defined in the scope of the loop, then maybe, but your loop wasn't doing what you wanted it to ;^).

Comment: Is it just me or does the inline `if` seem erroneous to anyone else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just:

```
for i in rand:
   LL.append(mylist[i])
```

Or better:

```
LL = [mylist[i] for i in rand]
```

But note that your code isn't well defined.  I think what you were attempting was:

```
LL = [ x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if i in rand ]
```

This will work, but it's unnecessary to iterate through the entire enumerated list unless you need to preserve the order from your original list.

Finally, if you just want to randomly select N elements from your list, [random.sample](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) is perfect for that.

```
import random
LL = random.sample(mylist,3)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use `numpy`, you can use advanced indexing here:  `np.array(mylist)[rand]` will be what you want -- But if you do that, **rand cannot be a tuple**.

Comment: Excellent, you've reminded me of `random.sample` - brilliant + 1

Comment: `random`'s a neat little module.  I don't know that I've ever actually needed it myself, but I've picked up a thing or two answering questions here on SO.  For example, I had no idea (before this answer) that `itemgetter` accepted multiple arguments.  Always learning ...

Comment: LL = [ x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if i in rand ] worked. building out random manually, thnks....

Comment: @Merlin -- if you don't need to preserve the order from your original list, `LL=[mylist[i] for i in rand]` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
from operator import itemgetter
LL = list(itemgetter(*rand)(mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

```
# just pick the items
from operator import itemgetter
print list(itemgetter(*rand)(mylist))

# pick 3 **actual** unique random items
from random import shuffle
shuffle(mylist)
print mylist[:3]

# Or as I've been reminded, and it preserves order of mylist (kudos @mgilson)
from random import sample
sample(mylist, 3)
```